# Operations with planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I think in the graph theory operations such as decomposition into cycles, union, intersection, difference, subdivision can be done.

- If I am given a *planar graph (for e.g. see figure)*, then can the above operation do same as irrespective from the *type of the graph*? That my question is what ever common operation like above can be done with any type of graph?
- Can anyone give mathematical notations for the above operations, for e.g. if I am given below graph, then how would be decomposition into shortest cycle, union of adjoining cycle, intersection, and difference can be represented?

[image]

Comment: You may want to explain what you are asking here, because right now the question is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unions, intersections, and differences

Graph [unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations) are probably what you'd guess they are.  If $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$ are two graphs, then $$G_1 \cup G_2=(V_1 \cup V_2,E_1 \cup E_2).$$

I've never encountered *graph intersections* nor *graph differences*, but MathWorld ([intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDifference.html); [difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDifference.html)) defines them as $$G_1 \cap G_2=(V,E_1 \cap E_2)$$ and $$G_1 \setminus G_2=(V,E_1 \setminus E_2),$$ respectively, where the two graphs are assumed to have the same vertex set $V$.

In many cases in graph theory, it's easiest not to have fixed definitions because often we will need to use a slightly modified definition.  Instead authors tend to give the relevant definitions when needed.  I suspect the same holds true for $\cup$, $\cap$ and $\setminus$.

There's nothing to stop you from performing the operations $\cup$, $\cap$ and $\setminus$ on arbitrary pairs of graphs.

### Decomposition into cycles

Decomposing a graph $G$ into cycles means to find an edge-disjoint family of [cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29) whose union (as defined above) is $G$.  I don't believe there's any particular notation for this, typically $\{C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_k\}$ or something similar would suffice.

Since vertices in cycles have [degree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexDegree.html) $2$, and the cycles in any decomposition are edge-disjoint, we must have:

> **Lemma**: If $G$ admits a decomposition into cycles, then every vertex in $G$ has even degree.

The graph you drew in your picture, therefore, cannot be decomposed into cycles.  Additionally, if $G$ is not the empty graph, then $G$ cannot have any [isolated vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29).

If you don't want the edge-disjoint property, then you're talking about a graph covering (rather than a decomposition).

### Planarity

One example of a non-planar graph is the $5$-vertex [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_5$.  If $G_1$ is formed from $K_5$ by deleting an edge $e$, and $G_2$ is the graph formed from $K_5$ by deleting the edges other than $e$, then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are planar graphs, and $G_1 \cup G_2$ is $K_5$, and thus is non-planar.  So, you can perform the operation $\cup$ on any two graphs, but it may take you outside of the family of planar graphs.

The intersection of two planar graphs will, however, be planar (since $G_1 \cap G_2$ is a subgraph of $G_1$).  Similarly, the difference of two planar graphs will also be planar.

### Subdivision

When we *subdivide* an edge $uv$, we (a) delete it (b) add a new vertex $w$ and (c) add the edges $uw$ and $wv$.  We can do this many times, to obtain some graph that's called a *subdivision* of the original graph ([ref.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29#Subdivisions)).

Again, I don't believe there's any common notation for this, aside from writing "subdivide the edge $e$" or similar.

Subdivision preserves the planarity of a graph, which is a fundamental part of Wagner's classification of planar graphs (known as [Wagner's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem); see also [Kuratowski's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)).