# Is $T_1+T_2$ planar if $T_1,T_2$ are trees with the same vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs

I have two trees $T_1=(V,E_1)$ and $T_2=(V,E_2)$.

My question is, supposing that $G=(V,E_1\cup E_2)$, can we conclude that $G$ is planar?

I think it's planar, because $G$ is created by the union of two trees.
Also i read  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345011/operations-with-planar-graphs) that shows union of two planer graph my not be planer.

Comment: Hint: There is a criterion for planar graphs concerning the number of edges.

Comment: Those conditions state that whether $G$ isn't planer, i want to prove my graph is planer.

Comment: Find a counter example?

Comment: Actually that this criterion will not help you, provided the vertex sets are equal. Since if $|V|=n$, then the union of the trees will have at most $2n-2$ edges and thus if $2n-2 > 3n-6$ then $n < 4$ which will always be planar.

Comment: The union of the paths $x,u,y,v,z,w$ and $u,z,v,x,w,y$ is the non-planar graph $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: And $K_{3,4}$ is the union of two **edge-disjoint** paths if that matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: elegant, concise & visually demonstrative. +1

Comment: Also $K_{3,3}$ is the union of two Hamiltonian paths. But your example is nicer because your two trees are disjoint.

Comment: $K_{3,4}$ is the union of two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths.

Comment: @bof That decomposition of $K_{3,4}$ is useful in a number of cases. My advisor liked to ask the following question in an undergraduate combinatorics class: if a graph contains two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths, does it necessarily contain a Hamiltonian cycle? $K_{3,4}$ is the smallest counterexample.

Comment: In what circumstances can we conclude union of two trees is planer? Thank you.

Comment: @Pop I don't think there are any natural conditions that let us conclude this. If you're trying to do this as one step of a larger problem - well, what is it you are trying to do? But probably the answer will be that a different approach is necessary.